# Mail Merge, Split, Protect, and E-mail Word 2013 Document

Tags: email, microsoft-word, mail-merge, password-protection

I have created the perfect form for time sheets at work.  My goal was to mail merge the pages with personnel data.  Then protect the document with a password so people don't accidentally change the form.  Then e-mail each individual page to the employees.

Is there a good way to go about doing this?  I can't mail merge a protected document.  I can't figure out how to split it by pages.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

### Mail Merge narrative:

Use a data source (I'm using Excel).
Use the Word doc (I'm starting with a generic, run-of-the-mill Word doc).
[image: Mail merge starting position]

**Select MAILINGS tab, "Start Mail Merge", Letters.**
[image: Start mail merge]

**Select "Select recipients", Use an Existing List...**
[image: Use an existing list]

Pick the Excel file.
**Insert your fields.**
[image: Adding the mail merge fields]

**Select "Finish and Merge", "Edit Individual Documents..."**
[image: Select edit individual documents]

A new document is made with a page per person. **Separate** the pages (copy/paste a whole page to a new doc), protect, save, and send.
[image: Mail merge separated into each specific page]

Comment: So I would manually copy and paste each page.  700 pages...  And I would have to do this any time the form changes?

Comment: Perhaps a VBA macro would do this for you-- separate the document and perhaps even tie in with Outlook to automate the email process. Are you interested in such a solution?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I thought the solution might be.  I am a programmer but VB isn't a specialty of mine.

Comment: Ah, VB is not VBA. It's not a big deal that it's not your specialty--frankly it wasn't the best programming language ever invented. I'll start working on a solution for you.

Comment: @Bil1, sorry, I'm not able to continue working on this at this time. It's harder than I thought and other things came up.

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-in for splitting a merge, then a macro you could use for the password...
http://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm 
for the add-in
then http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/macro-to-separate-mail-merge-document-and-password-protect-679588.html
for the password macro...

Comment: The second link just points to another web forum.  Please include the relevant information in your post, as it's unclear which posting in that forum is the correct answer.